# Android posting to Twitter

Tags: java, android

I have seen that there are a few good libraries out there. These seem to come with all the bells and whistles.

My application only needs to post a status update to a twitter account. Each time the user would have to enter their details. This is not the major part of my app, so I was wondering if there are any condensed libraries or simpler ways to achieve this without including all of the features that come with larger libraries.

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you use Twitter API only first time it will ask to Login, next time it will stores all the User credentials and allow user to post their Tweets without Login process. Would you like to have it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ACTION_SEND intent.  Any application capable of sharing, including a twitter and facebook apps if installed, listens for that intent.  The system will then show a dialog to let the user choose how they want to share the message.  Use something like the following code:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.share)));
```

Comment: thanks for the tip, i never knew that. Although useful I should probably not rely on my users having another app.